# Image first in CSS with responsive

Tags: css, image, responsive

I'm using bootstrap 'featurette' feature. On the page there is a text on the left and image on the right. when you shrink the browser size, they go on top of each other, with the text at the top and the image at the bottom. How do I change this so that the image is frist and then the writing underneath?

Ad example is here http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

If you notice the feature part you will see what I mean when you resize.

I have tried changing the float position as thats the only thing I can think of but it didnt work.

P.s just to clarify, I still want them the same place when over 756px (or whatever the size is) but just want the image at the top when it changes size in the example above.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Well both of them have float:left so I tried making the image float left and the text float right so that it goes in that order but that didnt work. And it messed up the order when it was at the bigger resolution

Comment: Maybe try Flexbox, you can order elements - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use display:flex property to the container for both and use order property for the elements for example is below. Try changing the order of the elements and have a look.

```css
.elements-container{
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
 }
.text-box{
  order: 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #ff0000;
  display: block;
 }
.image-box{
  order: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="elements-container">
  <div class="text-box">This is text</div>
  <div class="image-box"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didnt know you could add order to css. Im still learning css3. Thanks

Comment: Best of luck further, learn most of the css3 features from css-tricks website.